# react throws exceptions for defined property as undefined

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a child component wherein m updating the state and passing to parent

and in constructor i have set

```
mmtDLTh:false


mmtogDLTh()
{
  this.setState(prevState=>({mmtDLTh:!prevState.mmtDLTh}),()=>this.props.togtheme(mmtDLTh));
}
```

yet it says and in constructor i have set  **mmtDLTh** is  undefined throwing error at **setState** function

i have defined it in constructor i dont whats going wrong it may be in **setState**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `mmtDLTh` should be `this.mmtDLTh` in the callback to setState non ?

Comment: it worked with "this" its resolved .but the expected result not seen

Comment: Not sure I understand your last remark, the code works but there are still bugs in your app ?

Comment: this has resolved the undefined error but expected behaviour not working lemme check if not ill post another question

Comment: ok, I made my comment in an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

`mmtDLTh` should be `this.mmtDLTh` in the callback to `setState`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `mmtDLTh` as `state` property

```
state = {
  mmtDLTh:false
}
```

In `mmtoDLTh` function toggle its value and in `setState` 's callback you can notify the parent by calling parent function passed to child as `props`.

```
mmtogDLTh()
{
  this.setState(
   prevState=>({
       mmtDLTh:!prevState.mmtDLTh
  }),()=> this.props.togtheme(this.state.mmtDLTh));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

though the error had vanished but then functionality wasnt working  .
it worked with the following

> this.state.mmtDLTh

Comment: The issue with this approach is that your `this.mmtDLTh` and `this.state.mmtDLTh` will have different value after state change. Its better to put `mmtDLTh` in `state`. Your current code is working because on first time call `prevState.mmtDLTh` will be `undefined` and `!prevState.mmtDLTh` return `true` and from there onward your toggling the value of `mmtDLTh` in state.